# WebRTC: Unable to successfully complete signalling process using DataChannel

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I've been having trouble establishing a WebRTC session and am trying to simplify the issue as much as possible. So I've written up a simple copy & paste example, where you just paste the offer/answer into webforms and click submit.

The HTML+JS, all in one file, can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Ktmb3mVf

I'm on a local network, and am therefore removing the ICE server initialisation process to make this example as bare-bones as possible.

Here are the steps I'm carrying out in the example:

**Page 1**

1. Page 1 (loads page), enters a channel name (e.g. `test`) and clicks `create`.
2. A new `Host` object is created, `new PeerConnection()` and `createDataChannel` are called.
3. `createOffer` is called, and the resulting `offerSDP` is pasted into the `offer` textarea.

**Page 2**

4. Copy `offerSDP` from Page 1 and paste into offer textarea on Page 2, click `join`.
5. New `Guest` object is created, `PeerConnection` and an `ondatachannel` handler is set.
6. `setRemoteDescription` is called for the `Guest` object, with the `offerSDP` data.
7. `createAnswer` is called and the result is pasted into the `answer` textarea box.

**Page 1**

8. The `answerSDP` is copied from Page 2 and pasted into the `answer` textarea of Page 1, `submit answer` is clicked.
9. `Host.setRemoteDescription` is called with the `answerSDP` data. This creates a `SessionDescription`, then `peer.setRemoteDescription` is called with the resulting data.

Those are the steps carried out in the example, but it seems I'm missing something critical. After the offerer's remoteDescription is set with the `answerSDP`, I try to send a test message on the `dataChannel`:

**Chrome 40**

```
"-- complete"
> host.dataChannel.send('hello world');
VM1387:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'
```

**Firefox 35**

```
"-- complete"
ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
> host.dataChannel.send('hello world');
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

I also had a more complicated demo operating, with a WebSocket signalling server, and ICE candidates listed, but was getting the same error. So I hope this simplification can help to track down the issue.

Again, the single-file code link: http://pastebin.com/Ktmb3mVf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable webRTC clients to connect to each other, you need ICE. While STUN and TURN, which you don't need for such a test, are part of that, even without these helpers you still need to use ICE to tell the other end which IP/port/protocol to connect to.

There are two ways to do this: Google's "trickle ice", where the SDP (answer/offer) is passed on without any ICE candidates. These are then transported over a separate signaling layer and added as they are discovered. This speeds up the connection process, as ICE takes time and some late ICE candidates might not be needed.

The classic method is to wait until all ICE candidates have been gathered, and then generate the SDP with these already included.

I have modified your latest version to do that: http://pastebin.com/g2YVvrRd

You also need to wait for the datachannel/connection to become available before being able to use it, so I've moved the sending of the message to the channels onopen event.

**The significant changes to the original code:**

The interface callbacks were removed from Host.prototype.createOffer and Guest.prototype.createAnswer, instead we attach the provided callback function to the respective objects for later use.

```
self.cb = cb;
```

Both Host and Guest have an added ICE handler for the PeerConnection:

```
var self = this;
this.peer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    // This event is called for every discovered ICE candidate.
    // If this was trickle ICE, you'd pass them on here.
    // An event without an actual candidate signals the end of the
    // ICE collection process, which is what we need for classic ICE.
    if (!event.candidate) {
        // We fetch the up to date description from the PeerConnection
        // It now contains lines with the available ICE candidates
        self.offer = self.peer.localDescription;
        // Now we move on to the deferred callback function
        self.cb(self.offer);
    }
}
```

*For the guest self.offer becomes self.answer*

The interface handler $("#submitAnswer").click() does not send the message anymore, instead it is send when the datachannel is ready in the onopen event defined in setChannelEvents().

```
channel.onopen = function () {
    console.log('** channel.onopen');
    channel.send('hello world!');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion (adding createDataChannel to the guest as well, during initialisation) but I still get the exact same error. Here's my updated pastebin, I made your suggested change in the constructor function for the Guest object. http://pastebin.com/WbR50YZm

Comment: Are you sure that Host.id is referenced correctly? ( console.log(Host.id) ) ... I'm not sure if it works like that and they have to have the same name. If that's not it, I'll set up a page with your example. I've worked with data channels before, and never encountered a problem. They do work. :-)

Comment: For both the Host and Guest, the `id` is `test` (in the example), so it should be fine right? I also tried statically setting the name as `test` instead of using the `id` var, but neither seemed to work.

Comment: Ha! Sometimes one's gotta actually install something to understand it. :-) You're doing this across two pages and you're not handling ICE. You need a signaling layer to pass the ice candidates across the two pages - or test it all on one page. ICE is what tells webRTC how to connect. There's also the option to pass the ice candidates in the SDP (as opposed to trickle ICE). Let me see if I can hack that in there real quick. :)

Comment: There, the correct answer. :-) The message handling of the data channels still needs some work though.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. This works great. Would you be able to edit your answer again and add the few lines of code you added? This way it can provide a good summary of the missing bits without someone having to diff/parse the files. Specifically the parts about how you collect ICE candidates, and send an answer SDP back with the ICE info included?

Comment: Thanks, your example works perfectly, but I'm confused by the fact that you've only defined `onicecandidate` handlers, but don't actually do anything with the candidates (just wait for the empty one before the callback is made)... So, in the end just defining the callback and waiting for it to finish being triggered is all that needed to happen? (They get added automagically to the SDP?)

Comment: Yep. For classic ICE we really just need the handler to know when the process is finished - if it involves STUN or some dead interfaces, this can actually take a few seconds. When using trickle ice, you'd use the candidates provided there to send them over another signaling layer to the other end, where they are then added. If you for example have a direct connection the internet, but also some other interfaces, then the first candidate could already be viable and be used immediately, while the others are still being discovered. That's the advantage of trickle ice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, The ICE process makes a lot more sense to me now.